# In which layer extension methods will come in a 3 tier architecture

Tags: asp.net, .net, 3-tier

I am creating a 3 tier architecture web application, and I want to use extension methods. In which layer should I place the extension methods?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what the static methods do - if you add a bunch of MVC Html helpers, then presentation tier makes sense. And methods working on SqlAdapter / DataReader would be data tier etc. If these methods are reusable in other projects, you would probably want to separate them into utility assemblies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You place extension methods at any layer that uses them.

Extension methods can be extending base UI classes, BLL classes and/or DAL classes.

You place them near where they are used - if they are to be used in several places, you place them in a utility or core class/assembly.